# Искусственный интеллект. Нейронные сети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Вопрос будет чрезвычайно общим и в то же время полезным для тех, кто хочет этим заниматься, но не знает как найти подход к делу.

И так, я пересмотрел достаточно информации о нейронных сетях, примеры разных кодов, но все это было написано на уровень выше знаний обычного новичка С++.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, лекции, уроки или базовый пример нейронки, чтобы уверенно отталкиваться от исходного кода.

P.S Я очень мотивирован после просмотра разных тем с ИИ, но все таки боялся задавать этот вопрос, зная, что его заминусуют из-за слишком общей темы.*

**UPD 0:** Каким образом преподают этот предмет в университетах? Там хоть как-то задевают написание кода или сугубо теория с очень низким количеством практики?
**UPD 1:** Нашёл что-то [такое](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkwX7FkLfug&t=3301s), но не совсем ясна суть происходящего.
**UPD 2:** Ещё один [пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQo78WNGiow).
**UPD 4:** Вот пример структуры нейронной сети. Из этого выходит несколько вопросов:

- Что мы подаём *(или можем подать)* на входные нейроны и что мы получим?
- Что такое **"веса"**?
- *И в общем, вопрос не касающийся этого блока,* как мне хранить уже обученную сеть *(те же веса и т.д.)*, если я работаю с **консольным** вариантом программы? В файле?

[image: Нейронная сеть]

Comment: Нейронка это же по сути просто набор автоматически подстраивающихся коэффицентов. Язык программирования и подход (ООП или функциональный) не важны

Comment: Есть фундаментальная книга на русском - Каллан Р. Основные концепции нейронных сетей

Comment: @AlexanderduSautoy конечно, для начала хорошо иметь стартовый набор теоретических знаний, но он мало имеет отношение к практике создания существующих нейронных сетей.

Comment: куда делся `UPD 3`?

Comment: @Danis, was overridden by update 4

Answer (score 3):

Полностью с нуля написать современную нейронную сеть новичку достаточно сложно. Попробуйте для начала поработать с уже созданной нейронной сетью, чтобы понять основные принципы ее функционирования.

Например, если говорить про распознавание изображений - это сверточные нейронные сети (InceptionV3, VGG16). Чтобы собрать работающий сервер вам также потребуются библиотеки (TensorFlow, Theano) и фреймворки (Keras) для машинного обучения. В качестве стартового языка для разработки лучше используйте Python (для нейронных сетей этот язык - как PHP для web-разработки). В целом для ИНН (искусственный нейронных сетей) подходит любой язык, который быстро перемножает матрицы больших размеров.

Comment: Для начала я бы хотел просто уточнить для чего они нужны. К тому же, в разных примерах входные данные дробные числа (допустим `0.9, 0.1, 0` - это проценты или я что-то неверно понимаю? Выходные кстати тоже. И я так понял, это вероятность чего-то, ведь так?

Comment: @entithat это называется нормализацией данных. если на входы в математическую модель подавать абсолютные величины, выйдет ерунда (доминировать в этом случае будут переменные с наибольшими значениями).

Comment: @entithat да, на выходе у нас тоже будет процентная вероятность. нейронная сеть не может со 100% вероятностью предсказать результат (как и человек), на выходе всегда процентная вероятность возможных вариантов ответа.

Comment: @entithat если говорить про `чего они нужны`, то это классификация данных, распознавание образов, прогнозирование, моделирование событий, поиск оптимального решения.

Comment: @entithat совет на будущее - не заморачивайтесь сильно с теорией, возьмите один из мануалов с тем как установить и настроить нейронную сеть и сделайте это на практике, сразу многое станет понятно

Comment: @ Dmitry Maslennikov, полезные слова! Просто мне сложно сформулировать правильно мысль, не зная ничего наверняка точно. С какой задачи я могу начать свои первые шаги в этом? *(Задача вроде: идти гулять, если будет дождь и друзья.. и т.д.)?*

Comment: @entithat вбейте в поиске "создаем/настраиваем простую нейронную сеть". еще лучше смотрите примеры по этому запросу на youtube (только там большинство актуальных видео на английском).

Comment: @entithat также если хотите в этой области сделать что-то серьезное - совсем не помешают навыки системного администрирования. для работы, а особенно для обучения нормальной нейронной сети требуются хорошие вычислительные ресурсы. здесь даже обычный VDS не сильно поможет. в основном используют облачные вычисления (тот же AWS). если используете вычисления по графике, то желательны специальные инстансы с GPU (обучение будет идти раз в 20 быстрее, чем только с CPU).

Comment: Это уже чересчур:) Мне хоть бы базовые навыки понять..

Comment: @entithat пройдите для начала все этапы по работе с нейронной сеть - инициализация сети, подготовка обучающих данных и само обучение, а также взаимодействие с уже обученной сетью

Answer (score 2):

В общем, спустя 4 года, я получил некоторые знания, которые мне помогли понять что такое нейронная сеть (далее НС) и как с ними работать. Ответ не претендует на супер-профессиональную литературу и написан новичком для новичков. Надеюсь кому-то он будет полезным.

Коротко, НС - это набор функций, которые трансформируют данные с одного формата в другой.

#### Слои НС

НС состоит обычно из нескольких слоев: входной (input), скрытый (hidden) и выходной (output). Всегда есть входной слой данных (иначе как без них?) и что-то, что мы получаем на выходе. Суть НС в том, чтобы подобрать количество слоев таким образом, чтобы НС не переобучалась, но и выдавала какой-то адекватный результат.

> Переобучение - грубо говоря, когда предсказания НС будут очень плохими для данных, которые не похожи на тренировочные.

#### Нейроны

В свою очередь каждый слой состоит из какого-то количества нейронов. Звучит круто, но на деле это просто число, к которому применяется функция активации. А функция активации - функция, которая получает какое-то число из любого промежутка и трансформирует его в какое-то другое в более ограниченном промежутке.

> Кстати, входные данные принято нормализировать, чтобы НС обучалась правильно.

Примеры функций активации:

- ReLU (используют чаще всего)
- Sigmoid
- Линейная
- и другие

Каждая такая функция более выгодна в определенных случаях. [Более подробно о популярных.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/choose-an-activation-function-for-deep-learning/)

[image: NN]

Каждый нейрон соеденен между собой прямой линией (как на картинках), которая по факту ничего не значит. На самом деле связь нейронов состоит в том, что каждый cледующий нейрон это сумма каких-то предыдущих значений нейронов умноженных на коефициент - который по факту называют весами.

**Зачем нужны веса?** Если коротко, то они указывают на “полезность” входного значения.

---

На самом деле, НС не является самым лучшим вариантом, чтобы предсказать какие-то данные. В первую очередь использовать ли ее или какой-то другой алгоритм зависит от типа задачи. Если это классификация, то да. Если в предсказании Вы ожидаете какой-то промежуток значений, то это регрессия и НС тут уже не особо сможет помочь.

#### Как написать НС?

Если вы только хотите внедриться в сферу Data Science, то используйте tensorflow. Я когда-то пытался писать НС с нуля, так и забил, потому что оно стало слишком сложно держать всю математику в голове. А с такими библиотеками как tensroflow буквально пару строк и НС готова.

По сути Вам ничего не мешает написать НС в экселе. Просто надо терпение :)

---

#### Полезные каналы

- [StatQuest with Josh Starmer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtYLUTtgS3k1Fg4y5tAhLbw)
- [The Mathematics of Neural Networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5xKayCBOeU&ab_channel=ArtoftheProblem)
- [machinelearningmastery.com](https://machinelearningmastery.com/start-here/#getstarted)

P.S. Не хотел писать слишком много конкретной информации, чтобы не делать ответ еще длиннее, поэтому уложился общими терминами и понятиями.
Если у Вас есть предложения о дополнении ответа - смело предлагайте правку.

P.S. Хранить обученную НС можно как угодно. Зависимо от того, как Вы потом будете считывать обратно записанные данные. Но в целом достаточно хранить только веса и общую конфигурацию сети (кол-во слоев, нейронов).

P.S. На счет обучения в универе, то сначала идет обучение фундаментальных алгоритмов, линейных, логистических регрессий, SVM, Random Forest, KNN и тд. И под конец учёбы на 6-7 семестре будет что-то более приближенное к НС. Довольно интересно, но не всегда легко.